# Hotel reservation seasons Total Price between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my Season and Price table.

Version MsSql Server 2012

Below is the table structure
[image]

```
 user date input         
BeginDate : 2015-01-13     2 day  2*2 =4
EndDate   : 2015-01-18     3 day  3*2= 6
Total Price                          = 10
```

Total Price between date range (like hotel reservation seasons);
example sql query :

```
declare @DateStart date ='2015-01-13';declare @DateEnd date ='2015-01-18';
select *from Season s 
    inner join Price p on p.SeasonID=s.SeasonID
    WHERE (@DateStart BETWEEN s.BeginDate AND s.EndDate
       OR @DateEnd BETWEEN s.BeginDate AND s.EndDate
       or s.BeginDate BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd
       or s.EndDate BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd)
       and s.RoomID=1
```

How  to calculate total price with my dates range?

Comment: This is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Your example is vague and confusing.

Comment: sorry @FutbolFan  I did not understand the problem

Comment: Wouldn't the total be $12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a bigger dataset and a few more examples for us to help you make this query solid. But the core of the problem is to count how many day of each stay is spent in each `SeasonID`. Try this:

```
DECLARE @BeginDate  date = '2015-01-13'
DECLARE @EndDate    date = '2015-01-18'

;WITH
    tmp AS
    (
        SELECT  S.SeasonID,
                StayBeginDate = IIF(@BeginDate > S.BeginDate, @BeginDate, BeginDate),
                StayEndDate   = IIF(@EndDate   > S.EndDate,   S.EndDate,  @EndDate)
        FROM    Season  S
        WHERE   @BeginDate BETWEEN S.BeginDate AND S.EndDate
            OR  @EndDate   BETWEEN S.BeginDate AND S.EndDate
    )

SELECT      tmp.SeasonID, tmp.StayBeginDate, tmp.StayEndDate,
            DayCount = DATEDIFF(DAY, tmp.StayBeginDate, tmp.StayEndDate),
            Cost     = P.Price * DATEDIFF(DAY, tmp.StayBeginDate, tmp.StayEndDate)
FROM        tmp
INNER JOIN  Price   P   ON tmp.SeasonID = P.SeasonID
```

I trust that you know how to sum up the total cost for the whole stay.

Comment: Thank successful results